# iPhone battery drains quickly with little usage but only during the day

Tags: iphone, ios, battery

[image]

iPhone 11, iOS 15.1

My iPhone battery is draining a lot even with little/no usage and I don't know why. It's been like this for ages.

Here's some information I can provide:

- Battery does not drain much overnight, however **during the day** it always uses a lot of battery **even when the app usage each hour is minimal**. Why is the battery draining so much only during the day? If you look at the chart, you can see overnight 12am-9am is very little usage, then suddenly after 9am it depletes quickly. I wasn't using the phone at all from 9am-1pm and yet the battery percentage depleted quite substantially. What's the phone doing from 9am?
- This battery usage pattern happens consistently every day.
- Enabling low power mode does nothing.
- Disabling background app refresh does nothing.
- I factory reset the phone, did nothing.
- I uninstalled some apps that I suspected were contributing to it, no change.
- I disabled VPN, no change.

What else can I do to figure out (1) what is causing the battery drain and (2) how to improve the battery life? Is there some kind of diagnostic I can run? If I use the Console app on macOS, can I search for some logs to figure out if the phone is doing something nonstop during the day?

Comment: Can you provide information on battery health and app wise battery usage? My best guess is it is because of using auto-brightness or some specific app which you only use during day.